# Sort column by 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss'

Tags: jquery, sorting, datetime, datatables

I want to sort a table by a column date like 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss'. I use datatables 1.10.13. Here is how I setup the table:

```
el.DataTable({
responsive: true,
dom: 'Bfrtip',
lengthMenu: [
    [ 10, 25, 50, 100, -1 ],
    [ '10 rijen', '25 rijen', '50 rijen', '100 rijen', 'Toon alles' ]
],
buttons: [
    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
        extend: 'copyHtml5', text: 'Kopieer'
    } ),
    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
        extend: 'csv'
    } ),
    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
        extend: 'excelHtml5'
    } ),
    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5'
    } ),
    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
        extend: 'print'
    } ),
    $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
        extend: 'pageLength'
    } ),
    { extend: 'colvis', text: 'Toon kolommen'}
],
"language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Dutch.json"
}
});
```

After making an ajax call I load the table and everything works including the sorting options.

However, I have two date columns and sorting by date only works if I use:

`new Date(param).toISOString()`(example: 2016-10-27T16:47:59.000Z).

If i use `new Date(param).toLocaleString()` (example: 27-10-2016 16:47:59) the column is sorted as numbers instead as dates.

I have tried several ways and I know there is a lot of info on this all over the web, but also this attempt failed.

My latest try was including these two libs(as describred by https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) but I cann't get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

Any way to get the sorting option to work an 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss' is welcome. The answer to my question doesn't need to use the 2 libs above!

Comment: What is wrong on sorting on this string `2016-10-27T16:47:59.000Z` It will always work. You do not have to SHOW that date Or do you want 13-11-2015 to come after 09-12-2017?

Comment: You do realise that sorting by `dd-mm-yyyy` will convert `01-January-2000, 01-April-2017, 02-April-2017` to `01-April-2017, 01-January-2000, 02-April-2017`, right?

Comment: I want to show and sort by 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss' where 13-11-2015 comes before 09-12-2017

Comment: So sort on 2016-10-27T16:47:59.000Z and SHOW 27-10-2017

Comment: I gave it one last try using the data-order attribute option I tried before. I have 1 row which sums up some values of some columns but is also part of the table. The dafault value I inserted into the data-order attribute was wrong. Stupid, anyhow I got it working now. This question can be deleted if possible :)